# Forum Search engin to search keywords in database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a intranet forum in Php and MySQL and  **I am using ajax to display searched results on the same page** but right now I am using query LIKE text% to search in database which is slower. but I want to make it fast search engin which can parse *,+ and show result.

**Since I am using ajax i am not able to use free search engin,so if possible pls provide a complete solution**

Comment: I'm not sure what the extent of the problem is - do you experience slow speeds with like text%? what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Using LIKE %bla% will give all occurrences of bla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to search in a lot of tables of your database, and those are big you should use a text search engine such as Solr, Lucene or Sphinx (as commented before).

But if you need to search only in a few tables you could use mysql full-text search capabilities. They only work on tables with MyIsan engine, but it's easy to update them everyday with an stored procedure or with a trigger each time the parent table being updated. So you don't need to install a fully powered server to use full-text searches.

[Fulltext Search on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/), which is an Open Source and very powerful local search engine with APIs to many programming languages and good integration with MySQL.

Here is [some tutorial using Sphinx Search with PHP](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/01/11/sphinx-search-engine-and-php-installation-indexing/).

Comment: I am using ajax to show result so I just need a solution to make it search faster and also parse special chara like * ,+ etc and show result.

Comment: Sphinx is really fast, so using it with Ajax should not be a problem. Sphinx supports star search, but what is `+` for?

Comment: If you want to search with two key words like fooltball+Ronaldo similar to google. :)

Comment: Sphinx supports [boolean operators](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#boolean-syntax), but it seems that it uses an ampersand (&) as its `AND` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Zend Lucene -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Extract from website :

> Zend_Search_Lucene is a general purpose text search engine written
>   entirely in PHP 5. Since it stores its index on the filesystem and
>   does not require a database server, it can add search capabilities to
>   almost any PHP-driven website. Zend_Search_Lucene supports the
>   following features:
>
> - Ranked searching - best results returned first
> - Many powerful query types: phrase queries, boolean queries, wildcard
>     queries, proximity queries, range queries and many others.
> - Search by specific field (e.g., title, author, contents)